# Cannot pass one test case using Bellman Ford Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, graph, graph-theory

Problem Description

> Task. Given an directed graph with possibly negative edge weights and with  vertices and  edges, check
> whether it contains a cycle of negative weight.

> Input Format. A graph is given in the standard format.
> Constraints. 1 ≤  ≤ 103
> , 0 ≤  ≤ 104
> , edge weights are integers of absolute value at most 103
> .

> Output Format. Output 1 if the graph contains a cycle of negative weight and 0 otherwise.

Here is my solution:

```
import sys


def negative_cycle(adj, cost):
    #write your code here
    distance = [float('inf')] * len(adj)
    distance[0] = 0
    
    edges = []
    for i in range(len(adj)):
        for j in adj[i]:
            edges.append([i,j])
            
    for _ in range(len(adj)-1):
        for i in edges:
            a = i[0]
            b = adj[a].index(i[1])
            if distance[i[1]] > distance[a] + cost[a][b] and distance[a] != float('inf'):
                distance[i[1]] = distance[a] + cost[a][b]
                
    for i in edges:
        a, b = i[0], adj[i[0]].index(i[1])
        if distance[i[1]] > distance[a] + cost[a][b] and distance[a] != float('inf'):
            return 1
    return 0



if __name__ == '__main__':
    input = sys.stdin.read()
    data = list(map(int, input.split()))
    n, m = data[0:2]
    data = data[2:]
    edges = list(zip(zip(data[0:(3 * m):3], data[1:(3 * m):3]), data[2:(3 * m):3]))
    data = data[3 * m:]
    adj = [[] for _ in range(n)]
    cost = [[] for _ in range(n)]
    for ((a, b), w) in edges:
        adj[a - 1].append(b - 1)
        cost[a - 1].append(w)
    print(negative_cycle(adj, cost))
```

My code works for most test cases but fails on one test case.

> Failed case #12/19: Wrong answer
> (Time used: 0.23/10.00, memory used: 14229504/2147483648.)

The input format is
Number of vertices, number of edges
Vertice 1, vertice 2, weight of edge
...
...
... For all edges

May I know whats the error in this code?

Comment: Problem source link? So that we are sure it's not from any ongoing competition/test.

Comment: Hello, it's from UC San Diego's Algorithms on Graphs course on Coursera @tehillah

Answer (score 0):

`cost[a - 1].append(w)`

Here, you're not taking the cost of the edges properly. It should be `cost[a - 1][b - 1] = w`, the cost of the edge going from `A -> B`.

Comment: actually the entire main function was provided. I only had to edit the negative_cycle function. Is there any error in the negative_cycle function?

Comment: @Young42 It doesn't look right to me, as there can be many edges going from ```A``` to some other nodes. Can you share the problem link?

Comment: The problem is actually in a pdf. It is the second problem in wk 4. here's the download link https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/ZbXGTnQSSm61xk50EvpuTw_b5653e5869ef44c680fb84b29011bd72_course3_2020_07_27.zip?Expires=1657584000&Signature=DZEmId4xHvABp~FPfWwaD2TetIe5GA-5UHJ9ctjvWYNPWILBzSwwiuyMwGQd48lc~MTgvgTCxfgaDE7PK0yAdK9ZWoPGQW8s-xsNNaP1PkuYLDrhZR6UHOK7dcCWUbIvU1leN~lHNV1EbLjbbW-NTiPbUTkhcKjzJ7jZV9c1tFc_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A

Comment: I tried changing my code, but it still doesn't seem to be working. If I understand correctly, the original method should be correct as the code appends weights of edges to its neighbours for each vertice. @tehillah

Comment: yes, it's as you said, but your implementation uses ```cost[a - 1][b - 1]``` which isn't how the weights are being stored, so either you've to change the implementation or change the main function. 
You might want to take a look at this, [https://cp-algorithms.com/graph/bellman_ford.html#the-case-of-a-negative-cycle](https://cp-algorithms.com/graph/bellman_ford.html#the-case-of-a-negative-cycle).
Btw, the course doesn't allow to share solutions it seems, so I'm sorry I can't help further.

Comment: Hello, could you explain what you mean regarding the error in my implementation? I think I used '''cost[a][b]''' and not '''cost[a - 1][b - 1]''' as you mentioned @tehillah

Comment: @Young42 sorry that was a typo, I meant ```cost[a][b]```